# XIB localization failed in iPad

Tags: ios, localization, xib

My app support Traditional Chinese and English
Now I set my device language as Japanese
Well... In iPhone everything is fine, but iPad localization failed

If I set text used code, it show English when app running
Since app doesn't support Japanese it use English as default language

```
theLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("theKey", tableName: nil, bundle: Bundle.main, value: "", comment: "")
```

But if I set text used xib localize
xib base file↓
[image]

```
// English String
"fKW-21-ZWh.placeholder" = "Please fill in your skype ID";
"hyL-A7-fx9.placeholder" = "Please fill in your paypal ...";

// Chinese String
"fKW-21-ZWh.placeholder" = "請填入你的skype";
"hyL-A7-fx9.placeholder" = "請填入你的paypal";
```

it shows Chinese text when app running
I hope it can use English as default language
do I missing something?

What I did

```
TARGET -> Info -> Localization native development region = United States    
TARGET -> Info -> Localizations = [English, Chinese(traditional)]    
PROJECT -> Localizations = [Chinese, English - Development Laanguage]
```

Delete DerivedData, APP
Clean Project
restart computer

Edit
[image]

Edit
I found a Apple tech QA, [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1828/_index.html)
the language that app used is depend on  user language preferences

Answer (score 0):

Just select your storyboard/xib, go to File Inspector. In the Localization section, you can tick the language you want.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for replay, I think I already did it? please look Edit, or you means other thing?